# Inserting data, "MobileServiceTable must have a single id property defined"

Tags: java, android, database, azure

I'm currently developing an android app that requires data to be inserted into an azure Mobile Service DB. An id string and a first login integer, to be exact. However the following error is being thrown up.

> "IllegalArgumentException: The class representing the MobileServiceTable must have a single id property defined"

The id value that I need to insert into the database is being passed back from a fragment interface using passId(). Inside the override of this is where I am attempting to insert the values into azure as shown below.

```
@Override
public void passId(String id) {

    userInstance user = new userInstance();
    user.user_id = id;
    user.first_login = 0;
    mClient.getTable(userInstance.class).insert(user, new TableOperationCallback<userInstance>() {
        public void onCompleted(userInstance entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
            if (exception == null) {
                // Insert succeeded
            } else {
                // Insert failed
            }
        }
    });
```

The mClient var represents the MobileServicesClient as shown below

```
try {

      mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
              "https://xxxx.azure-mobile.net/",
              "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
              this);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The table name that I am trying to insert the data into is "user_table" if that helps at all.

I hope you're able to help, and thanks in advance for any help you guys give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Because the Azure Table that I was attempting to add data to auto created an "id" column, the user object that I was using to construct user info to insert into the database had to define an "id" String. As shown below:

```
public class userInstance {

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("id")
    public String mId;

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("user_id")
    public String mUserId;

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("first_login")
    public int mLogin;

}
```